# jQuery get JSON result with large decimals not working correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm using jQuery $.ajax to call a webservice.
The result is JSON data with a lot of data and large decimals.
In Fiddler, a result in JSON is displayed as

-1.34337916794034E+18

When I'm using Textview in Fiddler i'm getting the (right) result

-1343379167940340394.0

My ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        ShowLoader();
        request.setRequestHeader(requestHeaderName, requestHeaderValue);
    },
    accepts: "gzip, deflate",
    url: methodUrl,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: jsonParams,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (responseData) {
        return callback(responseData);
    },
    complete: function () {
        HideLoader();
    }
});
```

Why is this? Is this a problem in JSON / jQuery ?
The webapplication is also using ASP.NET (Forms).

Please help.

Comment: With floating points you have on the one hand the internal data, and on the other hand the _visual_ representation. Whether it is displayed as `-1343379167940340394.0` or as `-1.34337916794034E+18` depends on the implementation of the float to string conversation. It does not necessarily mean that their internal representation is different.  On the other hand this also means that if you _print_ two floats and they both show e.g.  `2` they are not necessarily equal.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that JavaScript's floating point number system cannot work (at least not precisely) with a number that long. You could try using a library like [Big.js](http://big-js.thatscaptaintoyou.com)

Comment: Floating points are never suitable for decimal calculation (in all languages, not limited to js), because no matter if you have large or small numbers, there are always inaccuracies.